# Embedded controller being restricted to template rendering only

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

In the [Symfony 2 template documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) it recommends embedding a controller within a template via the `render url` method and provides the following example:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {% render url('latest_articles', { 'max': 3 }) %}
</div>
```

This is fine, however is it possible to make this route only accessible to templates to prevent a user from accessing the url directly, and if so - what is the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define all you rendered controller routes pattern as "/_render/unique_name" or prefix them with "_render" and use access_control to secure the routes from outside world:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/_render, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        - { path: ^/_render, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Comment: I noticed this way of doing it but it seemed like a hack work around and I'm keen to follow the best practice. Do you know if this is the correct way to do it or is there no other way? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the same way you are securing internal ESI routes and this is the only way to secure routes so it is rather obvious to secure Controller routes which you want to hide from the browser client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by not defining a route for this method.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
        return array(
            'text' => 'This text is being included'
        );
    }
}
```

And then in the template

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ hello }}</h1>

    {% render "TestBundle:Test:test" %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but as @meze has pointed out, this no longer works in 2.2 and is advised against as embedding a controller this way bypasses the security layer which can cause system vulnerabilities.

Comment: I was not aware of this. Let this be an example of how not to do it then.